# Pointer Issues (Probably Easy)

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

This is probably something really basic but I just can't seem to see where I'm messing up.

I've got a vector of Cubes (a child class of the abstract class Node) that each hold a body object that contains the x and z positions of its position on a plane.  I'm attempting to move each in a "follow the leader" like style where the new position of a Cube is where the predecessor was before.

Since I'm using pointers this is where I'm a bit confused as at the moment, they are all going to the same position (wherever snake.x and snake.z is) so I know they are all pointing to the same piece of data.

Wonder what I need to alter so that each reflect the right coordinates.

```
 void updateChildren()
{
    Node * prevPiece;

    typedef std::vector<Node*>::iterator It;
    for(It curNode=nodes.begin(); curNode!=nodes.end(); ++curNode)
    {
        if (curNode == nodes.begin())
        {
            prevPiece = *curNode;

            dynamic_cast<Cube*>(*curNode)->body.xPos = snake.xPos;
            dynamic_cast<Cube*>(*curNode)->body.zPos = snake.zPos;
        }
        else
        {
            Node * tmp = *curNode;
            dynamic_cast<Cube*>(*curNode)->body.xPos = dynamic_cast<Cube*>(prevPiece)->body.xPos;
            dynamic_cast<Cube*>(*curNode)->body.zPos = dynamic_cast<Cube*>(prevPiece)->body.zPos;

            prevPiece = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if that is the problem, but a dynamic_cast can return a `nullptr` if the object is of the wrong type (in this case not a Cube). This should always be checked.

Comment: This is just a swapping problem.

Comment: You set each's position to the previous, but only after updating the previous' position to that of the one in front of him. If you do this in reverse order (rbegin, rend) it will work as you will read from nodes you haven't visited yet. You could also instead store the position of the previous node instead of the node pointer, and then modify it afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying the head and then setting any subsequent element to the same values of the head.

A quick fix would be to do it the reverse way, from the bottom up, so that when an element is assigned a new value, we know that its old value is no longer needed. This is achieved using `reverse_iterator`s:

```
void updateChildren()
{
    for(auto curNode = nodes.rbegin(); curNode!=nodes.rend()-1; ++curNode)
    {
        dynamic_cast<Cube*>(*curNode)->body.xPos = dynamic_cast<Cube*>(*(curNode+1))->body.xPos;
        dynamic_cast<Cube*>(*curNode)->body.zPos = dynamic_cast<Cube*>(*(curNode+1))->body.zPos;
    }
    dynamic_cast<Cube*>(nodes.front())->body.xPos = snake.xPos;
    dynamic_cast<Cube*>(nodes.front())->body.zPos = snake.zPos;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You assign the position of the the first Cube to the snake position, and then every subsequent Cube after that is just being assigned to this position.

Basically each iteration you are doing this:

```
  current.position = previous.position. 
  previous = current;  // The "previous position" has been overwritten

  ... next iterationn ...

  current.position = previous.position; // previous.position is the new vlaue
  previous = current;

  ...
```

You need to temporarily save the previous position before assigning it otherwise everything just get assigned to that.

Comment: Not exactly. At the end of the else it changes to the current node. It is just making space for a first element.

Comment: @DiegoSevilla Yes but even though his pointer of which is the 'previous" is correct - the position has already been modified. So the "previous position" no longer exists.

Comment: How do I prevent this though?  My skills with pointers are a bit weak so wondering where exactly I am modifying the position again

Comment: @Psychosupreme if you can step through with a debugger to see this yourself that would be the most helpful. Don't think too much about "pointers" in this context necessarily, just think about the value of position for each object.

Comment: @JustinMeiners I am still unsure what is wrong, before altering the currentNode I save its contents to tmp and edit it's content with previousNode.  After this the currentNode data is now the previous for the next node.
Without pointers this makes sense.  What I am worried about is how I am moving the data around with pointers and wondering how I avoid the required data being lost/edited.

Comment: @Psychosupreme ah got it. Ok so because it is a pointer you are not making a copy of the object, (like if it was an int) instead you just have another pointer to the same object. Either copy the object, or keep a tempPosX tempPosY instead of tempNode